# Spring MVC validator: error condition doesn't activate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

While following an official Udemy Tutorial I tried some Spring MVC Validation code, however, the validation condition doesn't activate; if I write the wrong values, I always see the confirmation page. How can I solve this problem?

If I leave the first field blank, there should be an error activated and it doesn't appear. Other cases all work fine, only the code never hits the error condition.

From Aircraft Model:

```java
@NotNull(message="is required!")
@Size(min=10, message="is required!")
private String airMan;
```

From Validator:

```java
@RequestMapping("/formProcess")
    public String openResult(
            @ModelAttribute("aircraft") @Validated Aircraft aircraft, 
            BindingResult Result) {
        
        System.out.println(" er: " + Result.getFieldError());
        
        if (Result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("error");
            return "index";
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ok");
            return "result";
            
        }
    }
```

From web form:

```html
<form:form  action="formProcess" modelAttribute="aircraft">

    <form:input path="AirMan"/>
    <form:errors path="AirMan" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
    <form:input path="airModel"/>
    <form:input path="airPower"/>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form:form>
```

Comment: You don't have a property `AirMan` but `airMan` your HTML is wrong. Also make sure you have an implementation for the validation, only the API is not enough. You need to make sure you have a hibernate-validator dependency in your classpath.

Comment: Also with airMan in html, nothing changed. And yes, I have in my classpath hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final and hibernate-annotation-processor-validator-6.0.17.Final (everycase, I don't see any error executing the program and Eclipse accept all code without error or import request). Thank, have you a solution?

Comment: Try @Valid spring annotation  instead of Validated.

Comment: Already done, also after and before @ModelAttribute, but nothing changed. Any other solution? Or, can you give me a very short example that sure works? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in spring-config.xml; in the code from original tutorial which I copy-pasted it wasn't this part. And also, in the head part:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

Before adding this those no error, no message, nothing. Only a validator not active.